# The FAQ has pictures from other sites and with the beta CSS

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, site-faq

I don't know how long it's been since I visited the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), but I found my way there today and noticed that all the example pictures (which I don't think existed before) show the CSS from beta sites, and one even shows the name of the site as "Bicycles".

It was jarring, since it didn't mesh with the CSS on the very site I was reading it on.  I think this would look better if it used our own site's CSS.

It is especially noticeable [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty), because it uses the CSS style for bounties directly next to a picture with a different CSS style for bounties.

Answer (score 1):

This is by-design.  The FAQ is the same for [all the sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) in the network.  Maintaining the FAQ using images for each site would be a bit...painful.  We used the bicycles site because any content should be easily understandable, and we wanted to use the sketchy site as it is easily recognizable to a large portion of our users.

Comment: That's not technically true.  Instead of images you could supply html, and the css would fix it.

Comment: I figured it was by design, which is why I used the feature-request tag instead of the bug tag.

Comment: @tzenes: That solves one problem while introducing a host of new ones... It's not impossible to make that work, but the benefit for the amount of work involved is probably not worth it. Or as Rebecca said, "painful".